# how to check is string contains substring?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with field name `out` of type `text`

I want to get the rows which contains sub string "hello and good morning"

I have tried to write:

```
select *
from my_table
where out like 'hello and good morning%'
```

but it seems not working.

How can I get all the rows which contains sub string ?

Comment: can this substring be present anywhere or is it like the text should be started with the given substring? can you please list down all the use cases, you want to match with? and please also add the inference from using the above code, like what is the exact behavior you want and what is the result of the above code.

Comment: If we go on the generic meaning of the terms you used, "get all the rows which contain the substring", you just need to add a `%` in front of the substring as well. `out like '%hello and good morning%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to given details, this should work.

```
select * from my_table where LOWER(out) like LOWER('%hello and good morning%')
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=856fb13ffa56249bf4ab8b0b5671aedc).